$0\le \alpha<2$,how to show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log^{2}k}{n^{\alpha}}$ is divergent
Question:$0<\alpha\le 2$,how to prove that:$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log^{2}k}{n^{\alpha}}$$is divergent?
My attempt to the question:I am tring to show that:$$\exists M>0,s.t.\exists N>0 ,\forall n\ge N,  \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log^{2}k}{n^{2}}>M$$ ($i.e.\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log^{2}k\sim O(n^2)$)
By using Stolz–Cesàro theorem we can conclude that:$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\log^2(k)}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log^2(n+1)}{(n+1)^2-n^2}=0$$However,this means that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log^{2}k\sim o(n^2)$,and i am stuck here.
Any help would be appreciated.

I think the easiest approach is to first notice that $\sum_{k=1}^n\log^2 k\geq n$ (for $n$ large enough), and that $n/n^\alpha$ diverges for $\alpha\in[0,2]$.

I didn't notice that before.Thank you!

As pointed out by ECL, the bound $\log k\geqslant \log 2$ for $k\geqslant 2$ shows that
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log^{2}k}{n^{\alpha}}\geqslant \frac{(n-1)\log(2)}{n^\alpha}\geqslant \frac{(n-1)\log(2)}{n^2}
$$
and it is known that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{n^2}$ diverges.
Notice that for $\alpha>2$, the series converges because $\sum_{k=1}^n\log k\leqslant n\log n$ and for $\beta>1$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log n/n^{\beta-1}$ converges because we can find $c_\beta$ such that for each $n$, $\log n\leqslant n^{\beta/2}$.
